# Is being called an オタク derogatory?

Tags: slang

This question spawns from the comments [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6986/1328).

I've heard that オタク could or could not be derogatory. During the times I've been in Japan and heard it used, I didn't think that it had any connotation of being an insulting term, but is this true?

I'm not sure about other countries, but in America as a borrowed word, many people are proud to be called an "オタク" depending on the circumstance. Is it not the same in Japan?

Comment: Do you consider "weirdo" or "nerd" derogatory?

Comment: @user1205935 That is what I'm asking. I'm not Japanese, so I don't know how Japanese think about オタク.

Comment: That wasn't a rhetorical question. I was actually wondering what you consider derogatory and what not. The nuance is much like "nerd", I would say, but I'm not sure, whether that should be derogatory or not. `X君は変わってるね` is definitely not derogatory and has a broadly similar meaning.

Comment: @user1205935 Oh I see. Well, I suppose it depends on the context. My presumption of it was exactly like the definition Teno posted. Which at first glance looks like a good thing, but there seems to be more to it.

Comment: Hmm... Well then, the answer to your question is "Well, I suppose it depends on the context." Maybe it's really the difference between politically incorrect and derogatory. オタク is politically incorrect (inasmuch as the term applies), but not necessarily derogatory. I would even argue that 外人(さん) falls into the same category... Both words can be used in a well-meaning way.

Comment: @user1205935: The question is, **are *nerd* (or *geek*) in English, largely inoffensive now, further along on the insult treadmill than *otaku* in Japanese?**.

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on the person who gets offended by being called so.

According to 日本語俗語辞書 ( http://zokugo-dict.com/05o/otaku.htm ),

> オタクとは、特定の分野に関して強い興味を抱き、関連するものを収集したり、詳しく知ることに時間を費やす人のこと。【年代】 1989年

To translate it, 「オタク」 means a person who has an strong interest on a particular field and spend more time for knowing the subject or collecting the related goods.

In my opinion, 「オタク」 used to have a negative connotation. It meant "nerd" except that the person's expertise doesn't have to be computers but often Anime, Manga, video games, or anything subculture. The term often implied social impairment of the person.

The origin of the word is not clear even for Japanese. It is said that when otaku people talked each other, they used 「お宅」 to refer to the second person instead of saying "you". Or they are kind of people who barely goes out but stays home. (「宅」 means home.) Or a columnist, 中森明夫, used it for the first time in a Manga magazine called, 漫画ブリッコ in 1983 ( http://www.nikkoku.net/tomonokai/toukou_card.html?snum=148).

About for this decade I would say, it has been used more openly to describe the person's characteristics which is maniac/specialized on a particular field with a positive connotation. But the term still suggests that the person is being obsessed about something and not normal/crazy/ill and less social so it may offend somebody who want to be considered normal.

「秋葉系」「キモオタ」 should be the alternative words for pre-オタク. The link describes the typical 「秋葉系」 although it is exaggerating to make it funny for a TV show. http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2130699281942633401

Comment: I wouldn't say that "nerd" is tied to computers. It seems to encompass all activities, which requires some kind of intellectual engagement, like programming, mathematics or just thick books.

Comment: According to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nerd , the definition includes "a boring or unpopular person, esp one obsessed with something specified a _computer nerd_"

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that オタク is still more broad than "nerd", since it doesn't just apply to intellectual stuff, but can also be applied to people who like to collect things that others would consider mundane like stamps, rocks, movies,Kit Kat flavors, etc.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 `I think that オタク is still more broad than "nerd"` -- It's covered in the answer starting with "It meant "nerd" except"

Answer (score 4):

Although I can imagine that オタク people may sometimes call themselves オタク proudly among themselves, I think that calling someone オタク is usually derogatory.  The word has negative connotations such as “narrow interest,” “not caring about anything except for a specific topic,” and “not sociable.”  See also [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na), sense [1]-5 and its remark.

As I understand it, the word *nerd* in English has roughly the same nuance.