# Addressing strangers without knowing the name

Tags: grammar, politeness

How does one address a stranger in a casual conversation when name is unknown?
For example, I had a conversation with an older Japanese lady and I wanted to compliment her on her English (but in Japanese, for some reason). Usually in such situations I might've gone something like

> ○○さんは英語上手です。 or ○○さんの英語は上手です。

But without the name it is quite difficult for me at this point. 
Using あなた　feels really rude, neither I'm comfortable relying on zero-pronoun and going 英語は上手です without any context.

Should I inquire about person's name in such situations? (obviously, not right before I have a sentence to use the name in).

Comment: You can usually use honorifics to avoid second person. 英語が **お** 上手ですね。

Comment: I believe this is essentially a duplicate of:
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/what-is-the-most-natural-way-to-refer-to-someone-when-you-dont-know-their-name/1433#1433

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As *YangMuye* explained, honorifics can be used to clarify first and second person without ever needing to use a first or second person pronoun. In that, usage of 謙譲語{けんじょうご} implies I'm talking about me. Usage of 尊敬語{そんけいご} implies I am talking about you.

An extended discussion about this topic can be read on the thread titled [そちら as a second person pronoun](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2644469). As far as I can understand, that thread can fully explain your question.

Comment: Thank you, it's the first time I've thought of politeness levels in that light, and it makes total sense.