# How politely to say "you"?

Tags: usage, politeness, word-usage, pronouns, second-person-pronouns

I found many variants in the internet, but they include `あなた`, which as I know isn't polite and better not to say it to a stranger.

So, if I don't know the name/last name of the person, don't know the job position (at work e.g.), how can I say politely `you`? 
Like: "Do `you` know?", "Are `you` `<Name of the person>`?" etc.

And is it polite to ask person about his/her name? If you forgot it.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17716/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4040/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2727/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first strategy is avoidance. No word for "you" is needed in either of your examples: ご存知ですか。〇〇さんですか。

In other cases, the prefix 御 (お or ご) serves instead. ご出身は？お子さんが素敵ですね！

In *very* rare cases where you actually do need to address someone, if you're being formal, そちら can be used in some cases (especially in contrast with oneself - like "and what about you?" そちらは？)

If you can't use そちら (it really sounds formal and distant), the strategies you listed are all okay: あなた is fine towards strangers when you don't have a better way of addressing them; asking for the name is perfectly fine when you don't already know it.

If you forgot the name... it's equally awkward as in any language, I suppose. You can always just bite down and 申し訳ありません、恥ずかしいですが、お名前を忘れてしまいました…？ (In an informal situation, ごめんなさい、お名前は何でしたっけ？) Awkwaaard... but quite polite.